# Why does NOT typeof undefined fail if something further up the chain doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeof

**Why does checking for NOT typeof === 'undefined' fail if the function is undefined?
And yet checking for NOT 'undefined' on specific object is safe?**

Here's my example: (and this does exist in my code)

```
if (typeof $.fn.dropdownn.Constructor.VERSION !== 'undefined'){
    //do something
}
```

I can add an extra letter to VERSION{N} and it still fails gracefully

BUT
If I add an extra letter to Constructor{r} it fails with "VERSION" undefined
If I add an extra letter to the actual function name dropdown{n}, "Contructor" is undefined.

(I'm test-adding an extra letter to synthesize not existing.
And the fact that it tells me the next object down the chain... from the one with the changed letter is undefined :: seems to imply that it indeed IS checking up the chain.)

What I want to check is whether a specific "VERSION" is in use.
In some cases a different "VERSION" will be in use.
In other cases this $.function.dropdown will be entirely missing.

But my question isn't "How-To". Rather it's "why is it like this?" ::

If dropdown.constructor.VERSION is undefined, then it would stand to reason that dropdownN.constructor.VERSION is undefined by the same check.

Yet, it seems if that function ($.fn.dropdown) is missing entirely, that the entire piece will fail as undefined

**Why isn't typeof safe to use either way? It appears typeof is restricted to the end object and not the entire chain of objects ??**

Comment: Please provide a clear sample of something that fails and what error it fails with, and something that unexpectedly doesn't fail and why you'd expect it to fail.

Comment: I think most likely your `$.fn.dropdown.Constructors` is an object which is why it works for you and it does not crash because it's not trying to access property of undefined object. Thus it is not related to the function `typeof` at all

Comment: "Why isn't typeof safe to use either way?" the typeof does not walk the "tree", it is just looking for the item you reference.

Comment: This may have completely changed the question. But I have now clarified my question. Which is "why does typeof !== 'undefined' fail if something in the "x.x.x.object" chain doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question:

"Before ECMAScript 2015, **typeof** *was always guaranteed to return a string for any operand it was supplied with*. But with the addition of non-hoisted, block-scoped **let** and **const**, using typeof on let and const variables *in a block before they are declared will throw a ReferenceError*. This is in contrast with undeclared variables, for which typeof will return 'undefined'. Block scoped variables are in a "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block until the initialization is processed, during which, it will throw an error if accessed."

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: This isn't related to the question being asked. The temporal dead zone doesn't have anything to do with property access.

Comment: thank you this helps me understand a bit better. But I have edited my question... quite a bit (apologies). I wasn't clear the first time on what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `typeof` operator does not guard against invalid use of values. Trying to access a property on `undefined` always throws an error. E.g.:

```
let foo = undefined;
foo.bar;  // error
foo.bar.baz;  // error
+foo.bar;  // error
typeof foo.bar;  // error
```

Any access of anything on `undefined` is an error, `typeof` doesn’t guard against that in the same way the `+` operator also doesn’t guard against it.